# All possible permutations of an array is not in the right order

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, permutation

A permutation of an array of integers is an arrangement of its members into a sequence or linear order.

For example, for arr = [1,2,3], the following are all the permutations of arr: [1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], **[3,1,2], [3,2,1]**.

For the array {1,2,3}

My code is giving the output as: [1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], **[3,2,1], [3,1,2].**

The correct output is: [1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], **[3,1,2], [3,2,1]**.

The last two permutations are not in the right order. Where am I going wrong with my code? I have used Java to write the code.

I have been trying to figure it out for hours, but I did not succeed.

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
    public void nextPermutation(int[] nums)
    {
        List<List<Integer>> permutations = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        generate(nums,0,permutations);
        System.out.println(permutations);
    }
    public void generate(int nums[],int index ,List<List<Integer>> permutations)
    {
        if(index==nums.length-1)
        {
            List<Integer> permutation = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
            {
                permutation.add(nums[i]);
            }
            permutations.add(permutation);
            return;
        }
        for(int i=index;i<nums.length;i++)
        {
            swap(nums,index,i);
            generate(nums,index+1,permutations);
            swap(nums,index,i);
        }
    }
    public void swap(int[] nums,int i,int j)
    {
        int t = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = t;
    }
}
```